# Yii2 Doing a Second Query on the Same Table from Results of First Query

Tags: mysql, subquery, yii2

I'm using the Yii2 Framework.

The bottom line is I'm asking how to query a table with the result of a query on the SAME table. There is a construct that allows you to compare a column of a table to the SAME column in a query. In my case I need to make the comparison with a DIFFERENT column.

For example:

```
$Products = Products::find()->where(['in', 'ChildId', $Query1]);
```

will compare all the ChildIds in the Products table to the ChildId values in $Query1 by default. I need to be able to compare ChildId to a different $Query1 column of values.

Here are all the details:

I have a simple table of IDs with 3 columns

```
 column1 = ParentId column2 = childId  column3 = Name
```

As you can probably guess these are categories that will be used to pull the products that fit them.
Each Product is assigned only a ChildId.
There are three levels of categories. Ex.  `Clothing -> Mens Casual -> Mens Athletic Wear`

Top level categories like Clothing have a ParentId of 1.

**Table: Productcategories**

```
ParentId     ChildId   Name
1           1      Root
1           2      Clothing
1           3      Jewelry
1           4      Accessories
2           5      Mens Casual
2           6      Womens Casual
5           7      Mens Athlectic Wear
```

On the Clothing homepage I want to display all the Clothing products however:

```
 $Query1 = Productcategories::find()->where('ParentId = 2')->asArray()->all();
```

only brings back the Mens Casual and the Womens Casual. (obviously I could include and where ParentId =5
but the point is I'm only trying to hardcode the highest level for the way the site works)
So the next step is to determine what ChildIds in $Query1 (5 and 6) are also parents (ans. 5) then retrieve
their children (ans. 7). Then I can grab all the products with a ChildId of 5,6, or 7 and complete the page.

So ideally I'd like to run the next three lines to accomplish that but this next line is not correct:

// Find those ChildIds of Clothing (in this case 5 and 6) that are also parents (ans. only 5)

```
$AlsoParentsQuery = Productcategories::find()->
    where(['in', 'ParentId', $Query1['ChildId']])->asArray()->all();
```

Problem: the $Query1['ChildId'] syntax is not valid. Only $Query1 alone will execute but of course with the wrong result
because it is comparing the ParentIds not the ChildIds.  Do you know a correct syntax?

// Now find the children of the also parents

```
$Query2 = Productcategories::find()->
    where(['in', 'ProductCategoryId',  
          $AlsoParentsQuery])->asArray()->all();
```

This turns out to be valid syntax and works if I can get the right $AlsoParentsQuery from the step above.

// Now grab the Products with the resultant Ids from Query1 and $Query2

```
$Products = Products::find()->where(['in', 'ChildId', $Query1])->
    orWhere(['in', 'ChildId', $Query2]);
```

This turns out to be valid syntax and works.

Any ideas how to get the $AlsoParentsQuery or equivalent working in Yii2?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make use of basic formatting options to make it readable.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!!! I couldn't figure out that... it wasn't as I copied it.

Comment: This is a big, complicated question that few people will want to spend time on. Please read about [minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In it's most simplistic form the question is how do you translate  SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column1 = 5) to Yii2 using activerecord objects. the rest called details is just an example of an application of this for clarity. Hope this helps.

Comment: SOLVED: Abandon where(['in', approach using arrays and use simple where() statements using objects.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Abandon `where(['in'`, approach using arrays and use simple `where()` statements using objects.

```
    //SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 IN (SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column1 = 8)// This needs to be executed in several steps:
    // Format:
    //$subQuery = YourModel::find()->select('column2')->where(['column1' => 8]);  //(SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column1 = 8)
    //$mainQuery = YourModel::find()->where(['column1' => $subQuery]);
    //$models = $mainQuery->all();
    // Do subselect first: (SELECT column2 FROM table WHERE column1 = 8). This will give all the 2nd level category records belonging to 1st Level - Clothing
    $subQuery = Productcategories::find()->select('ProductCategoryId')->where(['ParentProductCategoryId' => 8])->andWhere('IsActive = true');// Find records where a level 2 ProductCategoryId is the parent of a level 3
    $mainQuery = Productcategories::find()->where(['ParentProductCategoryId'=>$subQuery])->andWhere('IsActive = true');// Now get all the 3rd level category records 
    $model = $mainQuery->asArray()->all(); // had to ad the asArray() for a pagination count to work
    // Now getting all the products
    $query = Products::find()->with('productmedias')->where(['in', 'ProductCategoryId', $subQuery])->orWhere(['in', 'ProductCategoryId', $model]);
```